# Selenium: Why does initializing the Firefox webdriver from Python trigger a Windows Firewall alert?

Tags: python, selenium

- Python: 2.7.9
- Selenium 2.53.6

We drive Selenium from Python, and it works great.

Issue is that when we hit this line:

`driver = webdrive.Firefox()`

The Windows Firewall pops up, asking us to give permission to python.exe

We notice that we can ignore the firewall prompt, and everything seems to work OK.

Can anyone tell us:

- Why something in python land (selenium specifically) is opening a port
- The port open that triggers the firewall prompt is clearly NOT required, (since we can ignore the prompt, and web drier still works). What is the explanation for this?
- How we can , in code, suppress the firewall prompt? (e.g. by perhaps only allowing the engine to bind to 127.0.0.1 rather than the device IP?)

Answer (score -1):

> Why something in python land (selenium specifically) is opening a port
>
> Is this required?

your Python selenium code must communicate with a standalone server (geckodriver) over HTTP.  This can be a local or remote connection depending on your configuration... but you must allow this socket connection to use selenium with Firefox.

Comment: Thanks! Since I can deny the firewall request, and selenium still works, this is not a 1-1, but we would like to understand this aspect of webdriver, and understand the config options. Where can we find docs on these areas? Thanks!

Comment: This response, while correct, is not detailed enough to be actionable, and bypasses information in the OP.

Comment: 2 of the questions asked were seeking explanations, and a 3rd question was seeking something actionable ("How we can , in code, suppress it").  By answering the first 2 items, it was made clear that the 3rd question is not valid.  There is no actionable answer to the question besides "you can't do that".. I left that out since it was implied by the information already given.

Comment: OP Enhanced to engage your notes above. Thank you!